# paint graphics2D offscreen? then take part of it and show on screen

Tags: java, graphics2d

i want to paint a graphics2D component off screen then take part of it and show on screen for a live updating image, so buffered image takes to long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setDoubleBuffered( true );` in your JPanel. 
That pains it offscreen, and when it's done painting offscreen, it will be shown on the JPanel. 
You won't get black/unpainted frames anymore when using this.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [BufferCapabilities](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BufferCapabilities.html) (and related classes), as well as the graphics concept of [MultipleBuffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering).

Also, it's probably not BufferedImage that is slow, it's how the rendering pipeline utilizes (or doesn't utilize) the available hardware acceleration.

If, by chance, you're building a game, or some other app that needs high-speed rendering that takes advantage of hardware acceleration in Java, you'd be well served to start with a library that takes care of these details for you, like [Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/).

- [Getting started with Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/wiki/doku.php)
- [Webstart demos](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/static.php?page=demos) that show what you can expect (in terms of performance)
- [API documentation](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/)

One of the other really nice things about Slick2D is that it's cross platform, and takes care of the rendering performance details for you, because the actual rendering pipeline changes between platforms, JVM versions, and hardware (depending on the available features that are exposed to Java), and that's just a lot of details and trial/error you don't want to figure out on your own. BIG time sink.

LWGJL (the library that enables Slick2D's graphics performance) basically completely sidesteps Java2D, to enable this. There's some interesting reading in there if you want to dig deep.